# Cakephp and Laravel coexisting

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp

I do receive a chalenging task to migrate a old legacy cakephp 2 app to laravel 5.2.

The two must coexist and work togheter, while all modules are migrated to laravel because it is a large app.

Is it possible/feasible? the auth session credentials can be transported to laravel auth session easily?

What kind of traps you can find int this proccess? and how can i avoid them?

I have only found these steps : http://laravel.io/forum/09-08-2014-strategy-for-migrating-a-large-cakephp-project-to-laravel?page=1#reply-28620

Anyone already done this before ?.

Comment: You're saying two different things: first you say you're migrating a CakePHP app to Laravel, and then you say they'll coexist? Are you migrating one CakePHP app and letting that new Laravel app coexist with another CakePHP app?

Comment: inside a legacy cakephp app i must insert a laravel app and migrate funcionalities from cakephp to laravel, one by one, once at the time. after all funcionalities are migrated from cakephp to laravel, cakephp will be turned off and just laravel will exists

Comment: It would probably be easier to slowly migrate to Cake 3 since they are more similar and can share part of the code.

Comment: @josé-lorenzo Wich is the best way to migrate the models from Cake version 2 to Cake version 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The by far most logical solution would be to transfer the entire application over to Laravel at once. However, if that's not a possibility, it should still be possible. If you keep sessions in Redis, they'll of course be accessible by both applications. The main issues might be:

1. You want a User object on the Laravel app to authenticate, but authentication happens in the Cake app. Hence, you might need to reauthorise somehow in the Laravel application. However, if you know the session is valid and you have the user ID, you can do this without issue.
2. The session token is generated differently: Laravel will generate its token through one algorithm, using its application key. Without any knowledge of CakePHP, I'm confident the session key is generated differently. You might be able to surpass this by modifying the generation of the key for them to match. Otherwise, you'll end up with issues for hashing salts, CSRF verification and whatnot if those things go between the applications.

Comment: I will share the same database, i have a trait that checks if there is a user logged in how can i route from cake to laravel ? passing an entire url ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd do

Comment: header did no work 
`
<?php
    header('Location: http://localhost/mylaravelapp/public');
?>`

Comment: Even putting into the controller did not work : `class LaravelController extends AppController {
     public function index() {
      header('Location: http://localhost/mylaravelapp/public');
     }
 }`

Comment: one thing works hacking the webroot/index.php, but can i read the cakephp session into Laravel ? `App::uses('LaravelController','Controller');
$Laravel = new LaravelController();
if( $Laravel->faq() != "" ){
        header("Location: http://www.laravelapp.com/faq");
} else {
        App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');
        $Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        $Dispatcher->dispatch(
                new CakeRequest(),
                new CakeResponse()
        );

}`

Comment: The session is in memcached only need laravel to recognize that session as valid !

Comment: The only point remaining is to enable login in Laravel when login into CakePHP, i mean after login in cakephp let Laravel have a valid login for the user who log in